# html2canvas cannot convert and upload 1mb < size image in php server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas div to images converted, then images post to php, this process is only executed below 700kb images only, 700kb < size images cannot post in php. Please give some ideas and sample code.

my html code is:

```
<div id="popup_div">
    <h1>i put some special</h1>
</div>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="work_cards.php" id="myForm">
     <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
```

my query:

```
function capture() {
    $('#popup_div').html2canvas({
        useCORS: true,
        allowTaint: true,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
            $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream"));
            //Submit the form manually
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    });
}
```

work_cards.php code is:

```
$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);
//Decode the string
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
$url = "Kings_design";
//Save the image
file_put_contents('img/order/'.$url.'.jpeg', $unencodedData);
echo $_POST['img_val'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of `post_max_size` in `php.ini` greater than 1 MB as,

```
post_max_size="4M"
```

Comment: i change the post_max_size = "800mb" in php.ini file but same problem occure.

Comment: You also need to do similar setting in any proxy servers before the PHP code. e.g Apache or Nginx